# Value between bigger and smaller set

Tags: categorical-data

I must measure a value. To do so, I only have samples with known value and a measuring tool that can tell if the sample is bigger or smaller than the value to measure.
Once the measurement is complete, I've got two set: one which contains values that are smaller and one that contains values that are bigger.

For example, with those set [-5,-3,-5,-1,-2,-3] and [1,4,3,2,5,3] I can assume that the value has a high probability to be between -1 and 1.

But with the two sets [-5,2,-3,1,-2,-6,-4] and [7,3,-1,2] it is less clear.

Which tools can I use to find the range or the value and it's degree of confidence?

Thanks you.

Edit: as my question was not well formulated, here is how the data is gathered:
There is a reference sound with an unknow frequency. Then people are given sounds of other frequencies and they must tell if the tone is higher or lower. Thus the two sets.
With the data gathered, I need to find the unknown frequency and how much I can trust the result.

Comment: How did you determine that "the value has a high probability between -1 and 1" in the first set? The sets are disjoint, and moreover have more numbers outside of the [-1,1] range than inside of the range, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Please clarify your purpose. How do you measure the value? Do you mean difference of means and 95% confidence intervals?

Comment: Interesting question - but it needs some work. You would need to build some kind of model for how people's judgements work as the tones get close together (I presume not everyone is 100% reliable and the task is more difficult as they become closer). Then you can start to use that data you describe to perform inference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question...

In my opinion, the range *is* the range and has nothing to do with degrees of confidence: $range(x) = max(x) - min(x)$

For your problem, I think you should only compare $min$ and $max$ of $x_1$ and $x_2$, so you can see it $x_1$ is less than/more than/included in/part of $x_2$